# How to install Sahi Pro on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, automated-tests, sahi

I am very novice and beginner of Sahi Automation Tool. I have downloaded "install_sahi_pro_v452_20130205.jar" . After double clicking on that jar file it was opened on WinRAR explorer.

How can I install and configure Sahi Pro? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prerequisite:
Installation of Java and setting java in your system path (in environment variable).

Now follow the steps below for running jar file  as well as installing sahi:

1. Open command prompt and go to the folder where you have Sahi_pro jar file (install_sahi_pro_v452_20130205.jar).
2. Run the following command:

   `java -jar install_sahi_pro_v452_20130205.jar`
3. Click Next button at the bottom on pop up
4. Follow the further steps according to the pop up instruction